# How can I add miniature pictures to XFCE folders?

Tags: xfce

Running Xubuntu here, how can I add miniature pictures to the folders like in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The so-called "miniature pictures on folders" is unsupported by Thunar, the file manager in Xfce or Xubuntu, according to [this thread on Xfce forum](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9346) as quoted below.

> Unfortunately, Thunar does not support directory thumbnails (ala Windows). There has been [some work done](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3508), but nothing completed yet.

So you can't add miniature pictures like Windows in Xfce or Xubuntu, yet.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to enable thumbnails, open thunar (file explorer for xfce), and on the menubar go to `Edit > Preferences`, then on the first tab for the preferences window , under `Show thumbnails` choose "Local Files only"  or "Always", and close the preferences window.

Now on thunar menubar, `View > View as icons`.

Then press F5 or close and open thunar again.

Comment: I tried that but I still can't add thumnails to my folders.